# Validate SharePoint REQUESTDIGEST for a GET request?

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint

I have a WCF REST service hosted in SharePoint that uses SSOM.  The client web application sends AJAX requests containing the `REQUESTDIGEST` in a `X-RequestDigest` header.  I am using the typical `SPWeb.ValidateFormDigest()` for my `POST` requests to prevent CSRF vulnerabilities.  Works great.

Here's the weird part.  Our client uses HP Fortify, and it is reporting that our `GET` requests are vulnerable to CSRF attacks.  My `GET` requests are indempotent so this seems silly, but I must be compliant.

To get around it, I want to use `ValidateFormDigest()` in my WCF method for the `GET` request the same way I do for `POST`, but it throws this exception:

*"Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb."*

I tried setting `AllowUnsafeUpdates`, but that just makes the request succeed *without validating the digest*!

Is there a way to have `SPWeb` validate the digest within a `GET` request?

Answer (score 0):

HP Fortify gives recommendations, not edicts. If you think - and can prove - that the warning is spurious, then justifying the pattern should be treated as being compliant. Code analysis tools are not perfect.